# where is the `__class__` variable stored in python, or how does the compiler know where to find it

Tags: python, compiler-construction, cell, free, abstract-syntax-tree

python relies on the `__class__` variable to be in a `cell` for a `super()` call. It gets this cell from the `free` variables in the first stack frame.

The odd thing is though that this variable isn't in `locals()`, and it is when you just reference it from the `__init__` method.

Take for example this bit of code:

```
class LogicGate:
    def __init__(self,n):
        print(locals())
        a = __class__
        print(locals())
```

When you disassemble this you can see it somehow knows that `print` and `locals` are globals and `__class__` is a `LOAD_DEREF`. How does the compiler know this, before running the code. `locals`, `print` and `__class__` are just variable names to the compiler as far as I know. Also this way `__class__` is all of a sudden in the `locals()` even before it's copied into `a`.

```
4          10 LOAD_DEREF               0 (__class__)
```

while `locals`:

```
            2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (locals)
```

I'm asking because I'm working on skulpt a python to javascript compiler. And currently that compiler doesn't differentiate between `print` or `__class__` and attempts to get them both from the global scope.

As you can see from a printout of the ast of the above bit of code, the parser doesn't differentiate between `locals` or `__class__`:

```
Module(body=[ClassDef(name='LogicGate',
    bases=[],
    keywords=[],
    body=[FunctionDef(name='__init__',
        args=arguments(args=[arg(arg='self',
                                 annotation=None),
                             arg(arg='n',
                                  annotation=None)],
                       vararg=None,
                       kwonlyargs=[],
                       kw_defaults=[],
                       kwarg=None,
                       defaults=[]),
        body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print',
                                        ctx=Load()),
                                              # here's the load for locals
                              args=[Call(func=Name(id='locals',
                                                   ctx=Load()),
                                         args=[],
                                         keywords=[])],
                              keywords=[])),
              Assign(targets=[Name(id='a',
                                   ctx=Store())],
                           # here's the load for __class__
                     value=Name(id='__class__',
                                ctx=Load())),
              Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='print',
                                        ctx=Load()),
                              args=[Call(func=Name(id='locals',
                                                   ctx=Load()),
                                         args=[],
                                         keywords=[])],
                              keywords=[]))],
        decorator_list=[],
        returns=None)],
   decorator_list=[])])
```

Comment: I found part if the issue, in python2 you can't reference `__class__` from nowhere. And it doesn't to a DEREF.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or python 3? The `__class__` cell is a Python 3 hack to allow `super` to be called without any args.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `__class__` cell is a hack in Python 3 to allow `super` to be called without args. In Python 2 you had to call super with boilerplate arguments (ie.`super(<current class>, self)`).

The `__class__` cell itself is stored in the `<function>.__closure__` tuple. The index of the `__class__` cell can be obtained by finding its index in the `<function>.__code__.co_freevars` tuple. For instance,

```
>>> class A:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

>>> A.__init__.__code__.co_freevars
('__class__',)
>>> A.__init__.__closure__
(<cell at 0x03EEFDF0: type object at 0x041613E0>,)
>>> A.__init__.__closure__[
        A.__init__.__code__.co_freevars.index('__class__')
    ].cell_contents
<class '__main__.A'>
```

However, depending on the function, `co_freevars` and `__closure__` may be `None` if the function doesn't use cells. Further, `__class__` is not guaranteed to be present. The `__class__` cell is only present if a function called `super` is called without args (doesn't actually have to be super eg. `super = print; super()` will fool the compiler into creating a `__class__` cell) or if `__class__` is explicitly referenced and is not local. You also cannot assume that the `__class__` cell is always at index 0, as the following (albeit bizarre) code shows:

```
class A:
    def greet(self, person):
        print('hello', person)

def create_B(___person__):
    class B(A):
        def greet(self):
            super().greet(___person__)
    return B

B = create_B('bob')
B().greet() # prints hello bob

assert [c.cell_contents for c in B.greet.__closure__] == ['bob', B]
```

Comment: Great thanks! This definitely clears up how this all stuck together. And why all of a sudden that `__class__` var shows up. This is the PR I'm working on to add `super` to skulpt. https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/pull/694 it's a python2 implementation with some added py3 stuff. And finding the type of the class is turning out to be interesting.

Comment: Like I said, the implementation of `super` in py 3 is very hacky. It revolves around the compiler detecting that a function defined in a class calls a function called `super`, it then creates that function with a closure around the class currently being defined.

Comment: `__class__` (and subsequently `super()` calls) seem to break when wrapping classes with decorators that return new classes.

Comment: @Coburn I've never had a problem with with that. Maybe you should ask a new question with an example that shows the problem. If you do, please tag me in a comment on the question.