# Python get child class inside parent class static/class method

Tags: python, inheritance

The output of:

```py
class Dog():
    def get_class():
        return __class__

class Cat():
    def get_class():
        return __class__

print(Dog.get_class())
print(Cat.get_class())
```

is:

```py
<class '__main__.Dog'>
<class '__main__.Cat'>
```

I want to DRY up my code with a subclass. But the output of:

```py
class BaseClass():
    def get_class():
        return __class__

class Dog(BaseClass):
    pass

class Cat(BaseClass):
    pass

print(Dog.get_class())
print(Cat.get_class())
```

is

```py
<class '__main__.BaseClass'>
<class '__main__.BaseClass'>
```

How do I change the code in the second case to obtain the same output as the first case?

Comment: Code don't work. Either the method is static, either is takes a parameter. That code is incorrect

Comment: Did you try `print(Dog)` and `print(Cat)`?

Comment: @azro I can understand why you'd think so, but it actually does work in Python, to a limited extent. The `@staticmethod` decorator enables methods intended to be static to be looked up from an instance, but it's not necessary if the function (not a method!) will *only* be looked up from the class. In this case the class is simply acting as a namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are almost there :

```
class BaseClass:
    @classmethod
    def get_class(cls):
        return cls

class Dog(BaseClass):
    pass


class Cat(BaseClass):
    pass

print(Dog.get_class())
print(Cat.get_class())

<class '__main__.Dog'>
<class '__main__.Cat'>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different issues here.

1. The logic we are implementing is simply "get the class". If you want to do this starting specifically and only *from the class*, then there is nothing to do, and no reason to implement anything inside the `BaseClass` or `Dog` or `Cat` to get that result - because you *already have it*.

```
class BaseClass:
    pass

class Dog(BaseClass):
    pass

class Cat(BaseClass):
    pass

print(Dog)
print(Cat)
```

2. `__class__` is a special local variable that [is used for the implementation of `super()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45522210/). It names the class *where the method is defined*, regardless of how that method was looked up, or even if it was used as a plain function:

```
>>> class x:
...   def example(self):
...     print(__class__)
... 
>>> class y(x): pass
... 
>>> x().example()
<class '__main__.x'>
>>> y().example()
<class '__main__.x'>
>>> x.example(42)
<class '__main__.x'>
```

3. *Normally*, a method that does not expect to receive an instance of the class should be decorated with either `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`. This way, the code can still be used with either a class or an instance.

The rules are:
`@classmethod` - called with a class, the first argument is that class itself; called with an instance, the first argument is the instance's class. The parameters should include one at the start to receive that argument. By convention, we call that parameter `cls`.

`@staticmethod` - called with either a class or an instance, no argument is added for the call. The parameters should only list what will be explicitly passed.

No decorator - called with a class, no argument is added; called with an instance, the instance is added. **This should be used only for instances**, thus there should be a parameter to receive the instance argument. By convention, we call that parameter `self`.

Trying to use a function inside a class without either a decorator or `self` violates the standard expectations. It tries to treat the class as simply a namespace. This is *not what they are for*, even thought it *sort of* works.

---

Supposing that we want the code to work with either a class (giving us back that class) or an instance (giving us back that instance's class), the code is trivial: a `@classmethod`-decorated method already receives a parameter that is exactly what we want, in every case, so we simply return that. Thus:

```
class BaseClass:
    @classmethod
    def get_class(cls):
        return cls

class Dog(BaseClass):
    pass

class Cat(BaseClass):
    pass

print(Dog.get_class())
print(Dog().get_class())
print(Cat.get_class())
print(Cat().get_class())
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. In reality, I was trying to do more than get the class's name, and this was just a silly example that I though illustrated a minimum working example.  In this case, @classmethod was the decorator I needed.